# Using Power BI conditional formatting

Tags: powerbi, conditional-formatting

**Problem:**  When attempting to use conditional formatting on a card, table, etc. I can right click off the measure or column data involved to select conditional formatting.  The process starts and the conditional formatting window starts up, but never completes and appears as a “Pop Up” to select conditions.  It does show up as a second Power BI window.

**Context:**  I using a Mac w/ 16GB ram and running windows 10 via the latest version of Parallels. I am running the latest Power BI Version. Models are built from SQL Imports.  I have a Pro Edition of Power BI.  I have looked through the Options section of Power BI and applied everything that could be removing involved in this situation.  I am an analyst not a code writer.

**Questions:**

1. Is this a Power BI or Windows issue?
2. Are there any know resolutions to this type of problem?
3. What do I need to confirm or check on in Power BI

Comment: Hello Rick - why not report this as a bug to Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, here's what I see on Windows. I have selected a table visual. In the Visualizations pane, I right click a field. I select **Conditional formatting > Icons**. I get a pop up window that lets me configure the conditional formatting. It sounds to me like this is working for you just fine.

The popup window is large and cannot be resized. The **OK** button is at the bottom of the window, and if your monitor is too small, you won't be able to see it. I'm guessing this is the issue you are running into.

If you don't see the OK button on the bottom of the popup window, the simple solution is to use a bigger monitor or try dragging the window higher so you see the bottom buttons. If this isn't an option, one workaround could be "clicking" OK through key commands.

Here are the key commands that would allow you to "click" OK:

1. Click on the top most control to select it. In my popup window, it is the **Format by** dropdown.
2. Press **shift-Tab**. This selects the X button in the upper right corner of the popup window.
3. Press **shift-Tab** again. This selects the **Cancel** button on the form.
4. Press **shift-Tab** one more time. This should select the **OK** button.
5. Press **enter**. This should select OK and complete your changes.